# password_verify does not seem to work

Tags: php, hash, password-hash

I'm completely new to the password_hash and verify functions, but I've read the documentations about them on the default php website. I have problems with logging in when I hash passwords using password_hash. They are already hashed in the database.

This is my code I use to verify if the password entered in the form matches with the hash in the database (that has been generated with password_hash in a register form):

```
    $username = $kunaiDB->real_escape_string($_POST["uname"]);
    $password = $kunaiDB->real_escape_string($_POST["pword"]);

    $kunaiLoginQuery = "SELECT * FROM kunai_users";

    $kunaiLoginQueryResult = $kunaiDB->query($kunaiLoginQuery);
    $controlhash = $kunaiLoginQueryResult->fetch_array();
    $db_pw_res = $controlhash["user_pw"];

    if(password_verify($password, $db_pw_res)) {
        echo "Passwords match!";
    } else { echo "Passwords do not match!"; }
```

Whenever I log in it fails. I've tried to search for similar solutions but so far I've not found anything that worked. All help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is mistake in your SQL query. Add a `WHERE` clause.
Something like this

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE user_name_field = '{$username}'
```

And instead of

```
$controlhash = $kunaiLoginQueryResult->fetch_array();
```

Type

```
$controlhash = $kunaiLoginQueryResult->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Your Welcome. Consider up-voting and marking the answer correct.